# Can InDesign have different bleed margins for different pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, bleed

I'm working on a C# application to automate document creation along with some InDesign JSX, and whilst I'm setting up the classes, I understand pages can have different margins, but can they have different bleed margins as well?

Comment: Not sure InDesign permits such a differenciated bleed setting although the PDF boxes can be different within a PDF file. Not sure why you need this but you can still apply the max value by default for any single page.

Comment: Not all my pages are the same size and they require different bleed...wish this would be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, pages cannot have different bleed margins compared to other pages in the same document. Bleed is a property of the document preferences, hence it can only be set for the document globally.

Apart from that, I also wonder why one would need to set different bleed margins on different pages?

Comment: I was confused about a property in InDesign's javascript / COM interface. There's a uniform bleed margins property, which I was unsure whether it applied to being uniform across all edges, or, across all pages. If the latter, then it would imply that pages can have different bleeds which I would have had to change how I coded some things!

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing indeed, since the documentBleedUniformSize property is part of the documentPreference object, so one could make the false assumption that by setting it to false you could have non-uniform bleed between different pages of the document. However, the documentBleedUniformSize property determines whether all bleed margins of a page are uniform. See the InDesign ExtendScript API: http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/#DocumentPreference.html

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up to @mdomino on the "why" question.Oone such example might be in the case of multiple posters for a print campaign, where one or more sizes are printed using different machines/processes, (and as such might have different bleed/crop requirements).